# Problem in class design with multiple base model

Tags: c#, class-design

I have a base class for all the ENTITIES  of my project which is inheriting from below model :

```
public class BaseModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public override string ToString();
    }
```

Now I have 1 another functionality which is common for so many modules and I want to keep BaseModel for that functionality and want it to be inherited from it.

```
Public class BaseNotice
{
    // Common info related to notice which is use to send notice to employees in different scenarios
}
```

Now our every model is suppose to inherit from BaseModel so inheriting from BaseNotice will be multiple inheritance.

Now I cannot like below :

```
Public class BaseNotice : BaseModel
{
    // Common info related to notice which is use to send notice to employees in different scenarios
}
```

Because I would like to control functionality related to Notice from BaseNotice model and for notice I would like to keep BaseNotice as base model.

But I am not getting how to avoid multiple inheritance here and so what would be the proper way to design this?

Comment: What's wrong with multiple inheritence? Notice : BaseNotice, and BaseNotice : BaseModel... seems reasonable to me.

Comment: For things like this I would prefer an interface over inheritance because you are offering no shared behavior, only simple properties. Use `IBaseModel` and `IBaseNotice` and apply these interfaces where you need them.

Comment: Why do you think this involves multiple inheritance (which, strictly speaking, C# doesn't actually allow)?  You say "every model is supposed to inherit from `BaseModel`", but if it inherits from `BaseNotice` then it automatically also inherits from `BaseModel` - how is this a problem?

Comment: @Igor But using interface just for properties is good and recommended?because what i have seen uptill now is interface is mostly use when you want to force derive class to implement contracts

Comment: @DylanNicholson Actually i am talking about some situations where i need only BaseNotice in which i dont want BaseModel.

Comment: Ah sorry, misread your post.  If a "BaseNotice" isn't a logically type of "BaseModel", then what sort of objects would be both BaseNotices AND BaseModels? If they just need to have the ability to expose the same properties as a BaseNotice, containment (inheriting from BaseModel and containing a reference to a BaseNotice) might work better.

Answer (score 0):

There is No need to Multiple Inheritance. you can do that in this way:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public override string ToString();
}

public interface IBaseNotice
{
   // Base Notices Contracts should be placed here
}

Public class BaseNotice: IBaseNotice
{
    // Common info related to notice which is use to send notice to employees in different scenarios
}


public class ModelX:BaseModel
{
    public IBaseNotice Notice { get ; set; } 
    public ModelX(IBaseNotice baseNotice) 
    {
        Notice = baseNotice;
    }
}
```

Or you can use Second Generation of your BaseModel:

```
public class BaseModeNoticable:BaseModel
{
    public IBaseNotice Notice { get ; set; } 
    public BaseModeNoticable(IBaseNotice baseNotice) 
    {
        Notice = baseNotice;
    }
}
```